# How to pass JavaScript variable from Django-object in html template?

Tags: javascript, django

Here, I'm trying to convert the text to speech from django object and sorry to say that I don't know basic Js. Here is what I've tried.

**Code**

HTML

```
<p class="mb-1">{{ obj.reply }}</p>
<button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="txttospeech(obj.reply)">listen</button>
```

js

```
function txttospeech(txt) {
    var utterance  = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    utterance.text = txt;
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}
```

Comment: in `{{ obj.reply }}` there are some texts. And I want to convert it in audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replace `onclick` event with `addEventListener`, the following will get text from previous element or `<p>` as parameter for the `.speak()`

```js
function txttospeech(txt) {
  var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  utterance.text = txt;
  speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}

document.querySelectorAll('button.btn-dark').forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var textInput = this.previousElementSibling.textContent;
    txttospeech(textInput)
  })
})
```

```html
<!--
<p class="mb-1">{{ obj.reply }}</p>
-->

<p class="mb-1">This is speech test</p>
<button class="btn btn-dark">listen</button>

<p class="mb-1">hello world</p>
<button class="btn btn-dark">listen</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to pass value of `reply` attribute to `txttospeech` function then you should do like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="txttospeech({{ obj.reply }})">listen</button>
```

And if you want to cross verify whether value is actually getting passed. Then you can log in browser's console

```
function txttospeech(txt) {
    console.log("Value of reply attribute",txt);
    var utterance  = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    utterance.text = txt;
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing` `Uncaught ReferenceError`

Comment: actually function is not working and it shows `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`